# How to get the 2-D Array data in perl script?

Tags: perl, type-2-dimension

We have a client code which is written in perl, and it is trying to connect to a WebService to make an API call.

1. This API call is written in java, and it returns a 2-Dimemsion String Array.
2. Here is the code on Client side:

```
    eval {
            $service = SOAP::Lite->service("some WS link here");
    };
    if ($exception = $@) {
            print("Failed to connect to WS: $exception");
            return 0;
    }

    my $status;
    eval {
            $status = $service->getStatus();
    };
    if ($exception = $@) {
            print("$exception");
            return 0;
    }
```

My question is how to extract the actual data from this "$status" value. When I was to print this "$status" value, I can only see this:

```
     DB> p $status
     stringArrayArray=HASH(0x126e2ac0)
     DB>
```

Answer (score 1):

That means your modules has returned a hash reference. You can see what's in it with e.g. `Data::Dumper`

Or:

```
foreach my $key ( keys %$status ) { 
   print "$key => ", $status -> {$key}, "\n"; 
}
```

See: [`perlref`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html)

Comment: Thanks for the tips. But if I was using Data::Dumper, this is what I get: $VAR1 = bless( {
                 'item' => {
                           'item' => undef
                         }
               }, 'stringArrayArray' );  which totally lost me.

Comment: Your api is returning junk then. That's the root of your problem - you have a nested hash that you could access as: `$service -> {item} -> {item}` but it is undefined.

Comment: Thanks for the help. There is a tiny issue on the web-service side. And after I had it fixed, here is full set of data from dumper, "$VAR1 = {
          'item' => {
                    'item' => '0'
                  }
        };
". But there is still no actual data in the package. I guess my question is can client ( in perl ) really gets the full set of response from ws ?

Comment: Yes, of course. You don't have to use soap lite, you can manually process the response with LWP and a parser. This should at least give a hint.